# begin .map(callback()) from specific index

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run a callback function with specific start and stop indexes? I am practicing my JS and am writing a function to convert strings to camel case (from being '-' or '_' seperated) without altering the capitalization of the first word in the string. Basically, after I split the string into an array of words, I want to call .map() and start my callback on the second word in the array.
currently I have:

```
function toCamelCase(str){
  return str.split(/\-|_/).map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join('');
}
```

How can I get `.map()` to begin at `str.split(/\-|_/)[1]` ?

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, you can't. `.map` will iterate over an entire array.
You can chain `.map` to `.slice` though

```
function toCamelCase(str, start, stop){
  return str.split(/\-|_/).slice(start, stop).map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map()` always iterates the entire array. You can use the index (2nd param in callback) to return the word without changes if the index is 0:

```js
function toCamelCase(str){
  return str.split(/\-|_/).map((word, i) => i ? word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) : word).join('');
}

console.log(toCamelCase('the_camels_toes'));
```

BTW - you can use a regular expression with [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to to create the camel case:

```js
function toCamelCase(str){
  return str.replace(/_(\w)/g, (_, c) => c.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(toCamelCase('the_camels_toes'));
```